# pybind11: How to organize pybind module under a namespace package

Tags: python, c++, packaging, pybind11

In the below example of the pybind tutorial, a dynamic library is build.

`setup.py` in https://github.com/pybind/python_example:

```
ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension("python_example",
        ["src/main.cpp"],
        ...
        ),
]

setup(
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    ...
)
```

It can be imported like this:

```
import python_example
```

But this lives in the global namespace and I would like to organize it under a namepsace package like this:

```
import mypackage.python_example
```

It seems that regardless of where I put the `main.cpp` it will be always accessible under the global namespace. I am thinking of e.g. numpy, where everything is used as `np.somefunction` and never do I import from an other namespace.

Comment: Did you try changing "python_example" instead of moving the cpp file?

Comment: I am not sure where to apply the changes. The `PYBIND11_MODULE(name, variable)` does not except names like `mypackage.python_example`.

Comment: I see `setup_helpers.intree_extensions` but the docs are a little sparse.

Comment: Did you try changing the 1st argument of Pybind11Extension and nothing else?

Comment: @MarcGlisse hey, thanks a lot. That worked. I was under the impression that the name in `PYBIND11_MODULE` and `Pybind11Extension` have to be the same. So `Pybind11Extension("mypackage._python_example", ...` worked

Comment: @MarcGlisse I don't know the StackOverflow etiquette. Will you write an answer or should I do it myself.

Comment: I don't know if there is an official etiquette, but go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can add a namespace in front of the module name.

```
Pybind11Extension("mypackage.python_example",
    ["src/main.cpp"],
    ...
)
```

But the name in `PYBIND11_MODULE` should stay as it is.

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(python_example, m) {
```

This will add a folder during the build: `mypackage/python_example.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

This way you can import it like this:

```
import mypackage.python_example
```

Thanks to Marc Gliss for his answer in the comments.